# Variables are not appended in url in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

what i Need

- i need that on appending variable data url should in proper format.

url

```
url : "http://local-login.times.com/ticket_transaction/autosubmit_advance/"+evt_id/user+"?visitor_flag=1&source=get-direction-oneclick.
```

value of evt_id=2244 and user=45566.

problem is on appending these variable in url in jquery.

- on click on link 
  output

  ```
   http://local-login.10times.com/ticket_transaction/autosubmit_advance/0.012915232373744963?visitor_flag=1&source=get-direction-oneclick
  ```

but output should be

```
http://local-login.10times.com/ticket_transaction/autosubmit_advance/2244/4566?visitor_flag=1&source=get-direction-oneclick.
```

- where i have done wrong.
- any suggestion are most welcome.

Comment: `evt_id/user` divides 2244 by 45566, yielding the decimal you see in your output.

Comment: result of your division correctly appended.

Answer (score 2):

You are dividing the numbers in the string

```
+evt_id/user+
       ^
```

Hence why you are getting a decimal output.

```
+evt_id + "/" + user+
       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do `evt_id/user`, it will divide the numbers.

Do `evt_id + "/" + user` instead if you want to do concatenation.

See how to use the `+` operator for concatenation on [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition).